# Compiler error for modifying a non-const object

Tags: c++

```
 #include "iostream"
 #include "vector"


 class ABC {

  private:
      bool m_b;
  public:
      ABC() : m_b(false) {}

      ABC& setBool(bool b) {
          m_b = b;
          return *this;
      }

      bool getBool() const {
          return m_b;
      }
};

 void foo(const std::vector<ABC> &vec) {

      vec[0].setBool(true);
 }

 int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

     std::vector<ABC> vecI;
     ABC i;
     vecI.push_back(i);
     foo(vecI);
 }
```

When I compile it I get this error: passing `const ABC` as `this` argument of `ABC& ABC::setBool(bool)` discards qualifiers

Any ideas why this would happen since the object itelf is not a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

foo takes vec by reference-to-const, and you cannot change a const. So either remove the line that calls setBool, or if you really want to set the bool, change the argument type to std::vector&.

Or to be more strict about the implementation... You see, these two functions exist:

```
T& vector<T>::operator[](int);  
T const& vector<T>::operator[](int) const;
```

When you call "vec[i]" on a const object, only the second one is valid, so it gets selected. But this overload obviously returns T const&, and that's the thing you can't change.

Comment: To add some detail here, the vector has two operator[], a non-const one returning a reference and a const one returning a const reference. Because your vector is passed by const reference, the compiler picks the const operator[], so setBool is invoked on a const ABC (reference).

Comment: did he make it purposely? now we all see you had to edit it mwahaha

Comment: +1 to unwesen.  You should have made that an answer instead of a comment, it's less confusing than Iraimbilanja's answer.  I'd have upmodded you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`foo` takes a `const vector &`, meaning that the contents of the vector cannot be modified.  This, in turn, means that you are not allowed to call a non-const member function on any of the elements of `vec`, and `setBoo`.

Answer (score 0):

The object probably is const. Although the vector contains ABCs and not const ABCs, the vector itself is const, so when you call operator[] on it, the const version of the operator is used. The const version of operator[] on a vector returns a vector::const_reference. So, from what I can tell you are trying to call a non-const method on a const ABC&.

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround, you could store pointers to ABC objects in the vector and it will work fine - albeit at the extra cost of managing the cleanup. In this case you are not modifying the contents of the vector since the vector is only holding pointers.